# Куда деть css стили для PyQt приложения?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, архитектура, qss

Вопрос теоретического характера. Есть приложение на PyQt5 с огромным количеством стилей для всего, плюс ещё и разные темы можно переключать.

Куда можно их убрать из кода? Есть мысль парсить с `json`, но наверняка есть варианты более подходящие и удобные, ибо в `json` их будет неудобно редактировать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант

**main.py**

```
...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv    
    file = QtCore.QFile("dark.qss")                               # !!! dark.qss
    file.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly | QtCore.QFile.Text)
    stream = QtCore.QTextStream(file)
    app.setStyleSheet(stream.readAll())
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    w = Main()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**dark.qss**

```
QToolTip {
    border: 0.1ex solid #eff0f1;
    background-color: #31363b;
    alternate-background-color: #3b4045;
    color: #eff0f1;
    padding: 0.5ex;
    opacity: 200;
}

QWidget {
    color: #eff0f1;
    background-color: #31363b;
    selection-background-color:#3daee9;
    selection-color: #eff0f1;
    background-clip: border;
    border-image: none;
    border: 0px transparent black;
    outline: 0;
}
QWidget:item:hover {
    background-color: #3daee9;
    color: #eff0f1;
}
/* и так далее */
```

Comment: а помимо `readAll` можно ведь выборочно вытаскивать? и как тогда быть с двумя `QWidget` с разными стилями?

Comment: @type49 я не совсем понимаю что вы собираетесь вытаскивать. Вы спросили: "куда деть css стили для PyQt приложения?" Я вам показал вариант как это обычно делается.

Comment: Стили. То есть есть два QWidgeta с разными стилями, и подключать к ним стили как то так: .setStyleSheet(file['qwidget_one']['dark']), например. Ваш пример вроде как не рассчитан на одинаковые виджеты с разными стилями.

Comment: @type49 можно по разному, например так: `QWidget#centralwidget {...}` , `QWidget#widget {...}`

Comment: правильно ли я понял, что `centralwidget` и `centralwidget` из последнего комментария это имена этих объектов, объявленные в коде? Если да, то почему то не работает. Использовал `QPushButton#exit_button` для объекта `self.exit_button = QPushButton()`. Стиль не меняется, хотя файл прочитался нормально, принтом вывел. Мне создать новый вопрос или это относится к вашему ответу?

Comment: нижнее подчёркивание так же убирал

Comment: @type49  `self.exit_button.setObjectName('exit_button')`